# How is high tide related to tidal bulge?

Tags: classical-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, orbital-motion

This is going to be a basic question. But I'm confused at the conceptual level..

The following is a popular diagram explaining the tides:

[image]

I understand why the bulges appear on the right and left extremes corresponding to the moon's position shown in the image. What I don't understand is how this bulge is implying a high tide on the shore?

To be clear, lets consider a shoreline of ocean at the right extreme (where there is a bulge in the image). At this point, according to the image the height of water is higher from the surface. This seems to imply that the water in the ocean near that shoreline is getting pulled towards the right (towards the moon) - and thus the water on the shore should actually recede - so that the middle of the ocean could then bulge towards the moon. So it seems it should be a low tide.

I am having a tough time figuring out how the high bulge translates to water coming more towards the shore.

Answer (score 1):

I'm an avid sailor, and I live in Victoria where the tides are a major factor, so I think I can explain.  You are just thinking a little off.  If the "shore" is in the middle of the bulge (like where the little blue dot is in your diagram) then the tide will be high at that point.  But if the shore is on the top of the picture, then the tide will be low.  So the moon (80%) and the sun (20%) pull the water towards them and if the shore is there, then the water rises at the shore.

Remember that the tide goes through a full cycle: high-low-high approximately every 12 hours and 45 minutes.  So it is always moving one way or the other. I was just out sailing last night and take the tide and currents into account every time I plan a trip.

I believe there is also a very small tidal effect on the earth itself.

Comment: You haven't understood my confusion exactly, but thanks anyway. [This](https://youtu.be/pwChk4S99i4) video helped clarify my confusion. It's the cumulative squeezing affect that creates the tides and not just the gravity of moon and sun. The reason we don't see tides in lakes is because the cumulative squeezing is not significant compared to the huge oceanic expanse.

Comment: That is an amazing video. Thanks for pointing to it.  It has changed the entire idea.